# Cannot able to curl into service by using cluster-ip from a different pod , facing connection timed out with exit code 7

Tags: kubernetes

In the Minikube , I created a pod with the configuration provided below

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: node-js-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: node-js-pod
    image: bitnami/apache:latest
    ports: 
    - containerPort: 8080
```

then i created a service of type cluster-ip with configuration provided below

```
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: node-js-internal
   labels:
     name: node-js-internal
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8081
  selector:
    name: node-js
```

After creating the service i checked the cluster ip of service using command:
`kubectl get services -l name=node-js-internal`
which gave output as:

```
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
node-js-internal   ClusterIP   10.106.71.114   <none>        8081/TCP   18m
```

Once I created this service i tried to access this service internally from node-js-pod using command:
`kubectl exec node-js-pod -- curl 10.106.71.114:8081`
Which gave error message as curl 7 connection timed out :

```
$ kubectl exec node-js-pod -- curl 10.106.71.114:8081
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:10 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.106.71.114 port 8081: Connection timed out
command terminated with exit code 7
```

How to connect to the node-js-internal service from pod node-js in minikube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same port in the service as the container is listening to.

```
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: node-js-internal
   labels:
     name: node-js-internal
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
  selector:
    name: node-js-pod
```

If you want to have a different port in the service, than the container is listening to, you need to specify a mapping in the service

```
ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8081
    targetPort: 8080
```

Comment: I replaced the service configuration with port 8080 , `kubectl get services -l name=node-js-internal
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
node-js-internal   ClusterIP   10.99.125.181   <none>        8080/TCP   3m34s` even then i am facing the same error `kubectl exec node-js-pod -- curl 10.99.125.181:8080
 curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.99.125.181 port 8080: Connection timed out`

Comment: I had a typo in my example of the port mapping, please see the updated answer. If you are not doing a port mapping, are you using the correct port in the curl command? (8080)

Comment: The service selector does not match any pods, make sure to use the same name in the selector, as the pod is using. So:  `selector:   name: node-js-pod`

Comment: I replaced service configuration as  `apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: node-js-internal
   labels:
     name: node-js-internal
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
  selector:
    name: node-js-pod` and pod configuration as `apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: node-js-pod
   labels:
     name: node-js-pod
spec:
   containers:
   - name: node-js-pod
     image: bitnami/apache:latest
     ports: 
     - containerPort: 8080` After which on curling into service facing same curl 7 time out error

Comment: Since you are actually using the very same pod to make the curl test, could you try the curl with `http://localhost:8080`? Since you are inside the apache pod, that should work. If that works correctly, try `http://node-js-internal:8080/`to use the service.

Comment: curl to`http://localhost:8080` produces the output (It Works), but when i tried to curl to `http://node-js-internal:8080/`  produces curl 7 time out error .

Comment: Try it from within another pod, not the same that is actually providing the service.

Comment: Thank You for the reply , Now it started to work , I am able to curl into the service from another pod

Comment: i had the same problem - this answer works! Just `kubectl edit svc <service>`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add label to pod:

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: node-js-pod
  labels:
    name: node-js
```

Remember, service selects pods by their labels.

Comment: I added pod label as node-js-pod and added selector in service as node-js-pod,therefore my service configuration is replaced as `apiVersion: v1 kind: Service metadata: name: node-js-internal labels: name: node-js-internal spec: ports: - port: 8080 selector: name: node-js-pod` and pod configuration as `apiVersion: v1 kind: Pod metadata: name: node-js-pod labels: name: node-js-pod spec: containers: - name: node-js-pod image: bitnami/apache:latest ports: - containerPort: 8080 ` After which on curling into service facing same curl 7 timeout error

Comment: Thank You for the answer , Now it started to work , I am able to curl into the service.